# Ubuntu Live USB - Finding files that were stored on my flash drive

Tags: filesystem, files, live-usb, usb-drive

How can I find the files that were stored on my flash drive before I installed Ubuntu to it?

Edit: No, I didn't format it, my files are still on the flash drive root. I just need to know how to access them there.

Comment: installing an OS on a USB drive typically wipes the drive. unless you are willing to spend hundreds of dollars on professional file recovery, its likely not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are still present in your USB drive, then just plug in the usb when you are in windows or in linux, and a file-manager window showing the existing files will appear... (ie, pretty normally)

If you want to see the files of the USB *while* running from the Live USB then, you will need to:

- find out what is your USB drive *dev* directory (ex: /dev/sda1). Try looking with `df -h` (I'm not sure if the usb drive will appear there while running from a live image...try it)
- create a mount-directory: `cd && mkdir my_usb`
- mount the usb device into the mount-directory: `sudo mount /dev/sda1 my_usb` (replace /dev/sda1 with your usb-dev-directory)
- see the usb-drive files by looking inside the directory my_usb

From this moment untill you turnoff the pc, you can access (read and write) the files of your USB which will appear inside the `my_usb` directory

Tell if you got it working - cheers

Comment: @Walker, everyone once started learning from asking others for help, and that will be the way to grow forever inside a horizontal community :) Glad you liked your first help-pill, someday you may like giving help-pills yourself to others :) I try to and like it :)